Why does bash give a different $! (recent background PID) for (cmd && bash file1) & compared to bash -c "cmd && file1" &?
do command followed...
the first cmd give $! which is sub bash process pid but the second cmd git $! which is real cmd(test_link.sh)'s pid, why?
sea@sea-PC:~$ (cd /mnt/sda/tcpdump_monitor && ./mnt/sda/tcpdump_monitor/test_link.sh) &
[1] 69149

sea@sea-PC:~$ ps -ef | grep link
sea 69150 69149 0 10:31 pts/1 00:00:00 /bin/bash /mnt/sda/tcpdump_monitor/test_link.sh


sea@sea-PC:~$ bash -c "cd /mnt/sda/tcpdump_monitor && ./mnt/sda/tcpdump_monitor/test_link.sh" &
[1] 69176
sea@sea-PC:~$ ps -ef | grep link
sea 69176 68860 0 10:32 pts/1 00:00:00 /bin/bash /mnt/sda/tcpdump_monitor/test_link.sh


the diffrence between the two commands and why the diffrence for the recent backend pids?
I am focusing on the $! value because I want to run a script in the background for several hours and then kill it using the at command. The issue is that $! gives the PID of the created bash shell, not the actual command. Therefore, the following command will fail to kill the real command after it has been running for 5 hours
cd /mnt/sda/tcpdump_monitor && ./mnt/sda/tcpdump_monitor/test_link.sh & echo "kill $!" | at + 5 hours


Because of command grouping. (...).

If you want to consume the subshell, use exec. That is, (cd dir && exec process) will make the PID created by the ( be passed on to process. Otherwise that child is the parent of your process (subject to optimizations -- the shell can choose to do an exec automatically when it's safe to do so, but that's an undocumented implementation detail and not something that can be safely relied on).

Also, think about using { cd dir && exec process; } & -- because & creates a subshell, you don't need ( ) to create a second one. Again, this is a place where the shell can choose to optimize away a subshell, but it's not guaranteed to do so (and lots of settings/state can disable that optimization), so it's safer to assume it won't.

...what you're seeing in the bash -c '...' case is the automatic exec optimization taking place. Again, the shell can do this at its discretion whenever the optimization doesn't risk breaking other documented/guaranteed behavior (like execution of defined EXIT traps); no documentation says it will, no documentation says it won't, and code that assumes either way is faulty. When you want to be sure you'll get that behavior, use exec explicitly as I showed in an earlier comment.

That said, right now you aren't saying what behavior you want, so I'd argue that this question is incomplete. We can show how you to force either behavior, but please be clear which one you intend.

@CharlesDuffy  thank you for the thorough explanation! I now understand what happens when calling {cd dir && ./file} & or {cd dir && ./file} &. These commands create a subshell, right? Only when I use {cd dir && exec ./file}, will ./file run in a subshell without forking a new process. Therefore, I will get the correct running process of ./file when I add & at the end of the command.

Note that when using { and } the grammar is more particular about spaces and command separators than with ( and ). Anyhow -- with { cd dir && exec ./file; } on its own there's no fork at all so the exec consumes the shell that was running the parent script, but when you put a & after that it forces a single fork to the background so you get the behavior you want. So yes, your summary above is generally accurate.
